# Insert text from a file to specific line numbers on another text file

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed, editing

How can I insert text from a file to specific line numbers in another text file?
I was offered to use "sed", though with the flag "-i" there's no option to specify a text file, only "manually" loading text.

For example, how can achieve the following:

file1.txt:

```
55
66
```

file2.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I wish to add file1 content to file2 content in a specific line number so at finish I will have:

file2.txt:

```
1
2
3
55
66
4
5
```

Can I acheive this using "sed"? or is there any other method?

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` maybe:

```
awk 'NR==4{system("cat file1.txt")} 1' file2.txt
```

That says... *"Read `file2.txt`. If you have just read line 4, cat `file1.txt`. In general, print all lines - because `1` is true"*.

Or with `vi` maybe:

```
vi -c ':4:r file1.txt' -c ':wq!' file2.txt
```

That says... *"Load `file2.txt`. When loaded, goto line 4, read in `file1.txt`. Save and quit"*.

Comment: `^` for nice `vi` usage.

Answer (score 1):

And here it comes `sed` solution:

```
sed '3 r file1.txt' file2.txt
```